# Trying to run Automation Anywhere import API through Power Automate Cloud Flow

Tags: http-headers, multipartform-data, power-automate, rpa, automationanywhere

Have anyone tried to run Automation Anywhere A360 import API with HTTP Post action with Power Automate Flow?
The flow runs smoothly and I'm receiving the requestId in response. However, the whole action fails at the Automation Anywhere Control Room side with no imported bot at the end. I'm receiving the following error: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: Zip headers not found. Probably not a zip file?

Power Automate HTTP Post - Body

[image]

I added below code to the Http Post Body:

```
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-zip-compressed",
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"@{variables('fullPath')}\""
      },
      "body": "@{variables('contentString')}"
    },
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"actionIfExisting\""
      },
      "body": "OVERWRITE"
    },
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"publicWorkspace\""
      },
      "body": "true"
    },
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"upload\""
      },
      "body": "@{variables('fullPath')}"
    }
  ]
}
```

The contentString variable is: @{body('Get_file_content_using_path')?['$content']}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whoa, it’s all over the shop. The body should contain some basic JSON, it shouldn’t contain headers as well. Have you got this working in Postman? Hav you got doco to the API that I can refer to?

Comment: Yes, I got this working in Postman. The doco is this:
https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v2019/page/enterprise-cloud/topics/control-room/control-room-api/cloud-blm-import-api.html

Here's the CURL from postman:
curl --location --request POST 'https://community.cloud.automationanywhere.digital/v2/blm/import' \
--header 'X-Authorization: ..-7LX6VYkX--' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'upload=@"/C:/Users/marcu/Downloads/export.zip"' \
--form 'actionIfExisting="OVERWRITE"' \
--form 'publicWorkspace="true"'

Comment: My bad, I was confusing multi-part with form-urlencoded ...!  I'd suggest what you said is the case, i.e. it's not a ZIP file.  That'd be my take on it and I notice the doco is kinda sparse.  It appears as thought it wants a file locally as well?!?  My suggestion, try and give it a base64 string in postman that is the contents of the zip file because, if that doesn't work, I'd say a full file path is the only thing it would accept which will be a problem for PowerAutomate.  You may need to drop down to an Azure Function.